# CS0234: type or namespace name 'StudentViewModel.' does not exist in the namespace 'ContosoUniversity.ViewModels'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Error : CS0234: The type or namespace name 'StudentViewModel' does not exist in the namespace 'ContosoUniversity.ViewModels' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vqusln7le5fklxg/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9.jpg?dl=0

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
        {
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
            ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

            var students = from s in studentService.GetAll()
                           select s;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                students = students.Where(s => s.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                       || s.FirstMidName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
            }
            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "name_desc":
                    students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastName);
                    break;
                case "Date":
                    students = students.OrderBy(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
                    break;
                case "date_desc":
                    students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
                    break;
                default:
                    students = students.OrderBy(s => s.LastName);
                    break;
            }

            int pageSize = 3;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(students.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }
```

My Class

```
    using ContosoUniversity.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ContosoUniversity.ViewModels
{
    public class StudentViewModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Enrollment Date")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:g}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return FirstMidName + LastName;
            }
        }

        public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }

        public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<ContosoUniversity.ViewModels.StudentViewModel>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Students";
}

<h2>Students</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Student", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Last Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            First Name
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Enrollment Date", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DateSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            Date Of Birth
        </th>
        <th>
            Full Name
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstMidName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EnrollmentDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateOfBirth)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
<br />
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
    new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

I think something might be wrong with view model or automapper if need some more code please write to me!

Comment: A screenshot suggests that the problem is in View declaration. Can you post that? Also please specify in which namespace is `StudentViewModel` declared

Comment: StudentViewModel declared in ContosoUniversity.ViewModels

Comment: I just added a view, please could you check it?

Comment: Everything looks good so far. Are views and viewmodels declared in the same assembly? Also, just to double check, could you please post the full content of `StudentViewModel.cs`?

Comment: views and viewmodels folders in same project

Comment: and I changed a StudentViewModel.cs please check it